# Rails devise registration form when having STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-table-inheritance

I dont know how to create a worker and a association. So i am able to link those together. I have a type colulm in user.
This is my form(http://localhost:3000/workers/sign_up):

```
<h2>Create Worker</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

      <p><%= f.label :kodeord %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

      <p><%= f.label :bekraeft_kodeord %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

      <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
    <% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This is my models:

```
Class Worker < User
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end

Class Company < User
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end

Class User < Appliaction::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end
```

I want to create a register form that create a User and a Worker.
I have colums in Workers table as Name, Age and Adress that i want in the registration form.

Should it be a nested form and have should i create the association between worker and User table.

Best regards, 
Rails beginner

Answer (score 4):

Ok found the answer, what you have to is add the routes for your subclasses, and then dirrect the users to the relevant routes, like such

```
devise_for :companies
devise_for :workers
```

And then you probably going to want generate the view for each of them

```
script/rails generate devise:views companies
```

If there are no major differences in your view you can just render the file from the user templates in your companies templates like so

```
render :file => 'users/registrations/new'
```

In your controllers and view you will still use the standard   user_signed_in?

Hope it helps let me know if you find a better way

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Worker` [has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) `User`. I don't think you need to inherit your Worker class from User. If you want to create a User after creating a Worker, you can do so in a [after_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback.

Comment: I have a STI because i want worker and company to be able to login with the same login form. I dont have figured out how to create the form. I have tried to create a nested worker form in worker form. But it is impossable. I have also tried to add f.text_field :name to the registration form and it either is not working.